# Menu list keeps on growing every time I debug my Operator script

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, workflow, development

*This is a question about the process of developing an addon rather than a specific error in the script.*

I'm creating an Operator that I want to show up in the UV Unwrap menu.  I'm editing the script in the Scripting tab and every time I want to try the latest version of my code, I press the little arrow button to run my script. Unfortunately, every time I do a new entry is added to my menu list, so over a programming session my menu quickly fills up with lots of identical entries to run my operator.  I just want a single menu entry.  I thought my operators `unregister()` method would take care of this, but it does not seem to.

What would be a better workflow to develop my addon?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatProperty

class UnwrapWorldUvOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "uv.unwrap_world_space"
    bl_label = "Unwrap World Space Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    scale: FloatProperty()

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return obj and obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.mode == 'EDIT'

    def execute(self, context):
        print (self.bl_idname)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("uv.unwrap_world_space")    

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(UnwrapWorldUvOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.prepend(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UnwrapWorldUvOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: `unregister` doesn't get called automatically in the scripting editor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Custom Menu "Run Script" Button Causes Duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3402/31447)

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether `menu_func` is already part of `_draw_funcs` list and if so, do not prepend:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CUSTOM_OT_operator)
    
    if hasattr(bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.draw, '_draw_funcs'):
        if menu_func.__name__ not in (f.__name__ for f in bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.draw._draw_funcs):
            bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.prepend(menu_func)
    else:
        bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.prepend(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CUSTOM_OT_operator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_uv_map.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can some how "try" to unregister it before register in main function.

And also keep track of the last registered object, a quick way is set an attribute in bpy:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not getattr(bpy,'temp_addons', None):
        setattr(bpy,'temp_addons',[])
    try:
        add_list = getattr(bpy,'temp_addons', [])
        while add_list:
            old_addon = add_list.pop()
            bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(old_addon)  # Your addon
        unregister()
    except:
        pass
    register()
    getattr(bpy,'temp_addons', []).append(add_object_button)  #Your addon
    print(bpy.temp_addons)
```

Another better way might be define register() and unregister() more carefully, return object used inside that addon when using main function.

Comment: That is not doing anything when I run it.  Also, 'catch' should be 'except' in Python.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that menu is using object rather than bl_idname, then you might need to manually keep track of your menu object in some global place